# How to use useState with React-redux-firebase to re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state, react-redux-firebase

I'm exploring hooks with react-redux-firebase but my "setDataProducts" is behaving oddly.
I'm using useEffect() like I could use componentDidMount() but not sure if this is the right way.

```
export default function ProductList() {
    const [dataProducts, setDataProducts] = useState([]);
    const firestore = useFirestore();

    const fetchProducts = async () => {
        const response = firestore.collection("products");
        const data = await response.get();

        data.docs.forEach((product) => {
            setDataProducts([...dataProducts, product.data()]);
            console.log(product.data());
        });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchProducts();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            {isLoaded &&
                dataProducts.map((product) => {
                    return (
                        <div>
                            <h4>{product.title}</h4>
                            <h3>{product.price}</h3>
                        </div>
                    );
                })}
        </div>
    );
}
```

I cannot render the both products I have in Firestore. Only One is rendering... So I dont understand. Should not it rerender when state is updated ?

Thanks for reply

[We can see there was not rerendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXLBr.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is because you called setDataProducts again before dataProducts updated.

Please replace fetchProducts method with my code following:

```
const fetchProducts = async () => {
  const response = firestore.collection("products");
  const data = await response.get();

  const newProducts = data.docs.map((product) => product.data());
  console.log(newProducts);
  setDataProducts([...dataProducts, ...newProducts]);
};
```